# Прошу помощи по SQL, нужно объеденить два запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Первый запрос:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
                      tof_brands.BRA_BRAND, tof_suppliers.SUP_BRAND, tof_art_lookup.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER, tof_art_lookup.ARL_KIND, 
                      tof_art_lookup.ARL_ART_ID, tof_articles.ART_ARTICLE_NR, tof_articles.ART_ID, tof_des_texts.TEX_TEXT AS ART_COMPLETE_DES_TEXT
FROM         tof_articles, tof_suppliers, tof_designations,
                      tof_des_texts, { oj tof_art_lookup LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tof_brands ON tof_brands.BRA_ID = tof_art_lookup.ARL_BRA_ID }

WHERE     (tof_art_lookup.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER = '068103051G') AND (tof_art_lookup.ARL_KIND IN ('3')) AND (tof_designations.DES_LNG_ID = 16) AND 
                      (tof_articles.ART_ID = tof_art_lookup.ARL_ART_ID) AND (tof_suppliers.SUP_ID = tof_articles.ART_SUP_ID) AND 
                      (tof_designations.DES_ID = tof_articles.ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID) AND (tof_des_texts.TEX_ID = tof_designations.DES_TEX_ID)
```

Второй запрос:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('images/', GRA_TAB_NR, '/', GRA_GRD_ID, '.', IF(LOWER(DOC_EXTENSION)='jp2', 'jpg', LOWER(DOC_EXTENSION)) ) AS PATH
    FROM tof_link_gra_art
    INNER JOIN tof_graphics ON GRA_ID = LGA_GRA_ID
    INNER JOIN tof_doc_types ON DOC_TYPE = GRA_DOC_TYPE
    WHERE   LGA_ART_ID = 1075677 AND    (GRA_LNG_ID = 16 OR GRA_LNG_ID = 255) AND   GRA_DOC_TYPE <> 2
    ORDER BY    GRA_GRD_ID;
```

LGA_ART_ID = 1075677 // вот это значение подставляется из первого запроса и должно быть равно tof_art_lookup.ARL_ART_ID
На выходе хочу получить конкатенацию в отдельном столбце из выхлопа второго запроса т.к. там может быть более 1го результата.

Comment: ну самое простое видимо что бы первый запрос вернул только arl_art_id и весь его заключить в условие `lga_art_id IN(первый запрос)`

Comment: Не подойдет так, остальные данные из таблицы тоже будут нужны в дальнейшем.

Comment: Хм, вы ожидали другой ответ на _так_ заданный вопрос, странно ... ну сделайте join во from второго запроса с подзапросом в виде первого ... А на счет конкатенации чего либо из нескольких строк - так тут даже предположить, не зная какая СУБД, что либо невозможно, потому что это стандартами sql не оговаривается и в каждой БД есть собственные, уникальные средства (например group_concat в mysql) или их может вообще не быть.

Comment: база mysql, не могли бы вы привести полный запрос с join в нужном месте во втором запросе?

Comment: Кстати, совершенно не ясно, какие дубли подавляет первый distinct. при таком количестве выбираемых колонок повтор абсолютно одинаковых записей маловероятен, а если он все таки есть, то скорее всего там проблема с join и наклеивается что то не то, приводящее к размножению записей. А если distinct убрать, то тогда даже подзапросы никакие не нужны, просто все джоинете в одном from и все

Comment: хм, при _так_ заданном вопросе, видя только то что вы написали верно ответить вообще не представляется возможным. А примерно и скорее всего _не верно_ `SELECT ... FROM tof_link_gra_art .... JOIN (первый запрос) A ON A.ARL_ART_ID=LGA_ART_ID WHERE ...` а то что БД mysql должно быть отражено в тегах вопроса

Comment: там все таблицы от 5млн строк до 150млн строк поэтому совпадения там вполне реальны, в кажой таблице еще от 10 до 30 полей, так что далеко не все поля учавствуют в выборке

Comment: Когда вы пишите слово distinct вы должны точно понимать какие именно дубли, образующиеся из за участия в запросе каких данных из каких таблиц вы им подавляете. И эта информация _необходима_ для правильного объединения запросов

Comment: в первом запросе стоит where лишь для того чтоб ускорить тестирование запроса, в реальности мне нужно получить таблицу пройдясь абсолютно по всем записям из tof_art_lookup.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER для скармливания sphinx. Сейчас попробовал разные значения where в первом запросе с distinct и без него, на выходе разное количество строк из чего и делаю вывод что он нужен

Comment: Если количество строк разное и вы не знаете в точности почему, значит у вас не правильно сделаны join. А если даже все правильно, то нельзя сказать как выполнить join второго запроса что бы опять же чего нибудь не перемножить

Comment: вроде как составил но на выходе 0 результатов видимо гдето облажался https://pastebin.com/Lhd3MYQv // в комменты не пролазил такой длинный запрос